# How to act if a field is empty

Tags: jquery, validation

Good Day

I have a form that dynamically populates data into an html table.

I want to check if the td tags in the tbody are empty or not. If not, I want to display a new button that says: 'done'...or whatever

```
            <table class="borderClass">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tdProviderHead">Provider
                    </th>
                    <th class="tdCardNoHead">Card Number
                    </th>
                    <th class="tdCostHead">Cost
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: Provider"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: CardNo"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: 'R ' + Cost()"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try by counting number of rows in table ...!! As you using knockout for generating table rows

Comment: where do you want the button to get displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tbody tr td').each(function(){ // use .each function to iterate between td cells
        if($(this).html()==''){   // check whether any of the td cells are empty
            $(this).html('<input type="button" value="Done"/>'); // place a button to the empty td cell
        }
    });
});
```

html code:

```
<table class="borderClass">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tdProviderHead">Provider
                    </th>
                    <th class="tdCardNoHead">Card Number
                    </th>
                    <th class="tdCostHead">Cost
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Data">
                    <tr>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: Provider"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: CardNo"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: 'R ' + Cost()"></span></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

click here for demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swarne27/syTGA/)

or else if you want to check if one of the span tags are empty display a button elsewhere, use the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var emptySpan = false; // initialize a variable
    $('tbody tr td span').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()==''){
            emptySpan = true; // store the status if you find a empty span tag
        }
    });
    if(emptySpan == true){
    $('#notify').html('<input type="button" value="Done"/>');
    }
});
```

lets have a div outside the table or anywhere you want,

```
<div id="notify"></div>
```

Comment: yeah but I have an empty td cell, and still nothing happens.

Comment: in your code you do not have an empty cell, and when you say empty the whole <td> cell is empty that means you cannot have <span> tags or anything.

Comment: yes your right. If I extend the td to span, it works. Could you maybe alter your code so that only one button displays when ANY of the spans are empty (or not empty)...

Comment: thank you, but when adding code to the span tags, the 'done' button is still displayed... http://jsfiddle.net/syTGA/10/

Comment: No actually this does the trick.When ALL the span fields are filled, the button goes away. Thank you for your help, really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var tds = jQuery("table.borderClass > tbody > tr > td");

    var anyEmpty = false;
    tds.each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).text() == "")
            anyEmpty = true;
    });

    if(anyEmpty == false || tds.length == 0){
        // show button
    }
});
```

Comment: this works, thanks. How do you return the inverse? If it is filled?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("tbody tr td").length
```

Will give you the number of td.

You can if check any td is present and display button then

```
if($("tbody tr td").length == 0){
  // Do something
}
```

---

**EDIT :** Activity activity = activityManager.getByCode(activityShortCode);Just realized that `td` will be present but you want to check if they are empty. My solution will not work in such case as it just checks for number of `td` and not their content.  Others have given correct solution, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this:

```
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
   var txt = $(this).find('td').text();
   (txt == '') ? $(this).find('td').text('Done'): return true
});
```

Comment: thanks. but why does visual studio give me  syntax error at ;: return true?

Comment: You can try removing the `;` semis.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("table tbody tr td").each(function() {
   if(!$(this).text() || !$(this).html()){

   };
});
```

or

```
$.each( $("table tbody tr td"), function() {
   if(!$(this).text() || !$(this).html()){

   };
}
```